# Minutes difference between two timestamps in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two timestamps as below, I would like to find the difference in minutes:

```
end time = 2020-08-12T10:25:50.775+04:30

start time= 2020-08-12T10:50:50.775+04:30
```

I want to find the difference `end_time - start_time` in minutes in Excel.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your example, the answer is zero minutes.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld now it is fix thank you

Comment: Assuming you convert your strings into dates in Excel, the underlying value is the number of days since 1/1/1970 if I am right. The important point is that the floating point number is in days. That means that you can subtract the dates and get days or fraction of days thereof. Converting to minutes is trivial: x 24 x 60

Answer (score 1):

The format is not read as a datetime in excel. Assuming the time is in cell A1, you can apply this formula `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,12))`

You can perform arithmetic operations from the formula result i.e. Assuming start time is in Cell A2 and end time in cell B2, input into cell C2

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(B2,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(B2,12,12))-DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A2,12,12))
```