# Problem to get the difference of two timestamps in seconds in MS EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**The Problem:**

I got two timestamps in Excel (German version) in this format:

```
2023-01-28-10.14.20.123456
2023-01-29-11.15.21.123456
```

and I need the difference of these two timestamps in seconds - which would be 90061.

**What I tried:**

- To define a custom format for the timestamp:JJJJ-MM-TT-hh.mm.ss
- To define a custom format for the timestamp:JJJJ-MM-TT-hh.mm.ss.000000 but I cannot define the .000000 for the nanoseconds because I get an Excel error that this format cannot be used
- To use following formula =TEXT(D6-C6;"[mm]")
- I tried to use the formula in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63388773/minutes-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-excel) which translates to =DATWERT(LINKS(C6;10))+ZEITWERT(TEIL(C6;12;8))-DATWERT(LINKS(D6;10))+ZEITWERT(TEIL(D6;12;8))

Nothing worked so far - any hints are appreciated - Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, a slightly shorter formula
[image: screenshot illustrating formula proposed, which yields OP's target]

i.e.

```
=86400*(VALUE(REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3,"-","/"),".",":",1),".",":",1),11,1," "))-VALUE(REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","/"),".",":",1),".",":",1),11,1," ")))
```

or, auf Deutsch

```
=86400*(WERT(ERSETZEN(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(A3,"-","/"),".",":",1),".",":",1),11,1," "))-WERT(ERSETZEN(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(A2,"-","/"),".",":",1),".",":",1),11,1," ")))
```

(changing the UI language doesn't update the `,` with `;` though)

Comment: When I try this formula I get an error once the WERT / VALUE function gets allpied. The Timestamp re-formatting works fine. Wert seens to work when I cut out the faction of seconds. Any idea what I do wrong compared to your example? Thanks for your work

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher, because I have an English-language locale, I don't need any replacement for the `.` in the seconds component, you probably need an additional instance of REPLACE/ERSETZEN to make the `.` in the fractional seconds into a `,`

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher, völlig auf Deutsch: `=86400*(WERT(ERSETZEN(ERSETZEN(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(A3;"-";"/");".";":");11;1;" ");20;1;","))-WERT(ERSETZEN(ERSETZEN(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(A2;"-";"/");".";":");11;1;" ");20;1;",")))`

Answer (score 1):

So, brutally long, but works based on what you gave.
I assume that that format and the number of characters will not change.

((LEFT(A3,10)-LEFT(A2,10))*86400)+(HOUR(TIME(MID(A3,12,2)-MID(A2,12,2),MID(A3,15,2)-MID(A2,15,2),MID(A3,18,2)-MID(A2,18,2)))*3600)+(MINUTE(TIME(MID(A3,12,2)-MID(A2,12,2),MID(A3,15,2)-MID(A2,15,2),MID(A3,18,2)-MID(A2,18,2)))*60)+(SECOND(TIME(MID(A3,12,2)-MID(A2,12,2),MID(A3,15,2)-MID(A2,15,2),MID(A3,18,2)-MID(A2,18,2))))+((MID(A3,21,6)-MID(A2,21,6))*1000)

[image]

One way to reduce it is to put the time calculation used in hour, minute and second into a separate cell.

Comment: There seems to be two problems in your formula: for hour the multiplier should be 3600 instead of 3660 and there is a /60 missing in the first part of the secondfaction - that is why your result does not match mine of 90061. Thanks for your work it gave me the right idea.

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher 3660 was a typo, corrected. The milliseconds does have /60.

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher milliseconds needs *1000 after thinking about it... Will edit it.

Comment: Updated and added detail 1 day, 1 hour, 1 minute and 1 second...